# GLSA-check for Ubuntu or Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, security, reporting

[glsa-check](http://forums.vpslink.com/security/745-use-gentoo-glsa-check-keep-your-system-up-date.html) is a tool to report a server's exposure to known security vulnerabilities. Has anyone written a tool to do a similar thing for apt based systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Security HOWTO for Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch-sec-tools.en.html) which refers to vulnerability scanners like Nessus.  While not as Free as it used to be, Nessus is still considered the [#1 tool for UNIX vulnerability scanning](http://sectools.org/).

If you have the security repository for Debian or Ubuntu installed, you can apt-get upgrade to that without fear of installing new packages, and safe in the knowledge that (as much as the Debian/Ubuntu maintainers are on the case) you will get patched packages at the version that you chose to install.

Some people choose to automatically 'apt-get update; apt-get upgrade -y' if they are only using security; your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

http://lzone.de/Automated+Linux+Package+Vulnerability+Scanning

- Debian:  debsecan
- CentOS, Fedora, Redhat:  "yum list-security"
- OpenSuSE:    "zypper list-patches"
- SLES:    "rug lu"
- Gentoo:  glsa-check
- FreeBSD: Portaudit
- *nixes: lynis

Answer (score 1):

Nessus can do an external scans and will pick up on any problems it knows about with anything it finds listening on a port. However unless you use the Unix compliance (needs a professional nessus feed) module you can't check what is actually installed on the scanned host. By default it's pretty good with RedHat and will give you a list of packages that have had redhat advisories issued. AFAIK it doesn't to the same for Debian based systems, so it would need someone to write and maintain a plugin or nessus audit file that cross references DSA or CVE.

Answer (score 0):

GLSA is not a network vulnerability scanner as Geoff rightfully pointed, it's only a little script comparing the versions of emerged ebuilds against a list of vulnerabilites affecting official gentoo ebuilds. See here for details: http://gentoo.devel-net.org/glsa/readme

Nessus on the other way only checks a system from the point of view of the network, not locally and as such cannot find vulnerabilities like local root exploits.

I don't know of an equivalent in Debian but if you feel ok developing your own script have a look here:
[Debian Security Bug Tracker](http://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/), [Debian Security main page](http://www.debian.org/security/) and the [associated feed of vulnerabilities](http://www.debian.org/security/dsa).